# How to make Hosting View transparent in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, uiview, background

I need nearly all of the views in my app to have a transparent background, including TabView and NavigationView which by default have opaque backgrounds. I’ve mostly been able to accomplish by setting the default background of UIView to `.clear` by adding the following code to my `.onAppear()` function.

```swift
UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
```

However, while this works for most of the views, I noticed that Hosting View still retains its opaque background. So I was wondering how I might be able to make the background of this view transparent?

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/45yeq9n8bwbd0qm/AABLYKjTh8RRzh9DDXXsGMwEa?dl=0) is a view hierarchy capture of the problematic views when applying `.clear` to the UIView background. While I’ve actually managed to remove the background of these views using [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect.git), this workaround doesn't seem to work correctly when running my app on an actual device (some views remain opaque, others for some reason only become transparent after switching the color scheme during runtime). So how else might I be able to accomplish this?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try  `hostingController.view.isOpaque = false`
        `hostingController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

Comment: @RTXGamer I haven't tried that yet—where would I be able to access the hosting view controller?

Comment: Not sure how you're using HostingContoller in your codebase but added a sample to give you an idea.

Comment: @CodeSwift did you ever find a solution to this? Running into what I think is a very similar issue

Comment: @BrandonSlaght Sorry for the late reply! Unfortunately no. Until they change it, I think you'd have to try wrapping a UIView instead

Answer (score 1):

This will add SwiftUI View with `clear` background as a child view controller:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Testing Hosting VC")
            }
        }.font(.headline)
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
        hostingController.view.isOpaque = false
        hostingController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        addChild(hostingController)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh ok. I'm just using the view controllers that TabView and NavigationView use by default. Is there any way I'd be able to modify them, or would my only option be creating a custom TabView and NavigationView from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier and more straightforward to create a simple `UIHostingController` subclass:

```swift
import SwiftUI

public final class TransparentHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.isOpaque = false
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work? Where does `view` come from? This doesn't seem to compile as shown here.

Comment: Could you provide the exact compilation error @viraptor?
`UIHostingController` inherits from `UIViewController`, so it has a view. 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller

Comment: This works very well. Thank you Artem.